# Validate не проверяет все поля

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation

Есть такая форма:

```
<form id="form_orderform" >

    <label for="username">Ваше имя</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" minlength="2" placeholder="Иванов Петр" required />

    <label for="mail">E-mail</label>
    <input type="email"  id="mail" minlength="2" placeholder="mail@mail.ru" required />

    <button id="ordersend">Отправить заказ</button>
</form>
```

Проверяем с помощью jQuery [Validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org):

```
$('#ordersend').on('click',function(){
                
    var validator = $( "#form_orderform" );
    validator.validate({  submitHandler:function(){} });// убираем стандартную отправку формы

    if(validator.valid()){
        // Ajax - отправка данных
```

Все бы хорошо, но при нажатии только первое поле является обязательным и проверяется (хотя если ввести неверный E-mail адрес появляется сообщение, которое удаляется при нажатии по кнопке).

Почему это происходит и как исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, validator критичен к валидности кода. И если вы не указали  у `<input>` атрибут `name`, то это вызывает ошибку. Ошибки можно увидеть в дебаг-режиме:

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true
});
```